# Calculation of nuclear binding energy from atomic masses

Tags: nuclear-physics, binding-energy

The binding energy $B_\mathrm{nuc}(Z,N)$ of a nucleus of proton number $Z$ and neutron number $N$ satisfies
$$B(Z,N) = (Z\cdot m_p + N\cdot m_n - m_{\mathrm{nuc}}(Z,N)) \ [1], $$
where $m_p$ is the proton mass, $m_n$ is the neutron mass and $m_{\mathrm{nuc}}(Z,N)$ is the mass of the **nucleus**. For convenience, it is preferable to work with atomic masses as they are easier to calculate. Rearranging the above equation, we can write it as
$$B(Z,N) = (Z\cdot [m_p + m_e] + N\cdot m_n - [m_{\mathrm{nuc}}(Z,N)+Z\cdot m_e]), $$
where $m_e$ is the electron mass. Naïvely, as done e.g. in these lecture [notes](https://indico.cern.ch/event/145296/contributions/1381140/attachments/136908/194246/lecture8.pdf), we can now say that $m_p + m_e = m_\mathrm{atom}(^{1}H)$ and $m_{\mathrm{nuc}}(Z,N)+Z\cdot m_e = m_{\mathrm{atom}}(Z,N)$, with $m_\mathrm{atom}(^{1}H)$ being the **atomic** mass of protium and $m_{\mathrm{atom}}(Z,N)$ being the **atomic** mass corresponding to the nucleus $(Z,N)$, to arrive at
$$B(Z,N) = (Z\cdot m_\mathrm{atom}(^{1}H) + N\cdot m_n - m_{\mathrm{atom}}(Z,N)) \ [2]. $$

However, I wonder if this is actually correct since we have neglected the electronic binding energy in the equations $m_p + m_e = m_\mathrm{atom}(^{1}H)$ and $m_{\mathrm{nuc}}(Z,N)+Z\cdot m_e = m_{\mathrm{atom}}(Z,N)$. In the first equation this is not much of an issue as the electronic binding energy is only $13.6 \ \mathrm{eV}$, roughly a million times smaller (even more when $Z,N$ are large) than the nuclear binding energy we are trying to calculate. However, in the second equation I would expect it to actually be an issue, since the total electronic must be quite large for "heavy" atoms.

As a **very** naïve estimate of the electronic binding energy, suppose we put in one electron at a time, considering the system as hydrogen-like with the nuclear charge partially screened by the previous electrons. We would then estimate the total electronic binding energy $B_\mathrm{el}(Z,N)$ as
$$ B_\mathrm{el}(Z,N)=\sum_{Z'=1}^{Z}(-13.6 \ \mathrm{eV} \cdot (Z+1-Z')^2) = -13.6 \ \mathrm{eV} \cdot \frac{Z(Z+2)(2Z+1)}{6}.$$
Taking $Z=N=50$, we would get $B_\mathrm{el}(Z,N) \approx 600 \ \mathrm{keV}$ and $B_\mathrm{nuc}(Z,N) \approx 10 \ \mathrm{MeV} \cdot 100 = 1000 \ \mathrm{MeV}$. Thus, neglecting the electronic binding energy, it seems that we would make an error roughly at the per mille level.

In conclusion, I wonder if equation 2 is actually an accurate approximation of equation 1 or if, as I fear, neglecting the electronic binding energy would make it inaccurate, at least for moderately heavy nuclei.

Comment: Why are you using 13.6 eV for all the electrons? Ionization energies are complicated! See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energy & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energies_of_the_elements_(data_page)

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you for your comment! I am not using 13.6 eV for all the electrons, I am using 13.6 eV * (Z+1-Z')^2, where Z+1-Z'  is the screened nuclear charge (see Bohr model for hydrogen atom in the first link you posted). As I indicated in my post, it is a very naĩve/rough estimate mainly intended to find the order of magnitude. Summing up all the ionization energies for Mo from the second link, I would say that my rough estimate is an underestimate, making my question all the more justified.

Comment: Ah, right. I just skimmed your equation & didn't read it properly. Sorry about that.